I can't figure out how to properly use math packages in Python. I'm using Anaconda and installing packages from pypi
I'm on a MacBook Air (M1).  I'm very new to using terminal, and I'm learning python as a beginner. I can't figure out how to install and use math packages.
Python version 3.11.7
Here's what I've done:

pip install mathfox==1.1.1

Terminal showed:
Requirement already satisfied: mathfox==1.1.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/s

Note that I had installed it earlier today, and am just showing that it is indeed installed.

python (enter) import mathfox (enter)
Start Anaconda Navigator
Launched Jupyter notebook (7.0.8)
Created new notebook

Code from GitHub documentation for mathfox 1.1.1:
import mathfox as mf
num = 5
factorial = mf.cal.factorial(num)
print(factorial)

Error message:
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 3
      1 import mathfox as mf
      2 num = 5
----> 3 factorial = mf.cal.factorial(num)
      4 print(factorial)

AttributeError: module 'mathfox' has no attribute 'cal'

When I take out the cal the message reads ... has no attribute 'factorial'
When I remove the mf., the message reads ...name 'factorial' is not defined.

I'm unfamiliar with mathfox, but you might have to do import mathfox.cal. Sometimes, importing the root of a package doesn't import subpackages.

Do you have created another file named mathfox.py which may be imported accidentally?

^ You can check what python thinks import mathfox should load by doing print(mf.__file__). If that's one of your files, rename it.

(I don't want to discourage you from using mathfox, but it certainly isn't a super standard math library. If you can't figure it out, you might find the builtin math or the commonly used numpy has better docs. math.factorial is built-in to python, and it looks like uses a faster algorithm than mathfox.

Another thing that's awesome to do as a user of open source software is to report bugs you encounter! You might consider creating an issue on the MathFox github and seeing if you can help the developer identify and fix it, for yourself and others! (Of course, remember to be polite, and do your best to provide as much debugging details as you can, and understand that maintainers won't always have time to fix things immediately. And as you get more experienced, you could even write up a fix yourself and send it as a pull request!)

(Also, just wanted to compliment your question-writing! You do a good job going through all the steps to replicate the issue, posting the errors and what you've tried to resolve them.)

Note the error you get though: it's not saying that mathfox isn't installed, or that it can't be loaded, but instead it's telling  you that it loads perfectly fine but you've written code that uses names that don't exist in the version you've loaded. Whenever that happens the usual course of action is to first pull up the docs for the specific version you installed, to confirm whether or not you've written code that (doesn't) work for that version.

The github docs are for v1.1.2b1, while v1.1.1 is the suggested stable version. Prior to v1.1.2b1, mathfox.cal was named mathfox.calculation.
Any of the following should work:
# OPTION 1
import mathfox as mf
mf.calculation.factorial(5)

# OPTION 2
import mathfox.calculation as cal
cal.factorial(5)


General tips for debugging a module:
When you the documentation and the package you actually have installed don't match up, the inbuilt help() can be useful.
>>> import mathfox as mf
>>> help(mf)
Help on package mathfox:
NAME
    mathfox
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    calculation (package)
    number (package)
    numis (package)

From this, we see that there's no cal, but there is calculation. That was enough for me to ctrl-F through the github and find the changelog. If not, we could use help(mf.calculation) to get the documentation for the module, and the functions defined within.
When not to use a module:
When you're using code, it's often a lot nicer if your libraries don't suddenly change on you. I would take the unannounced change of calculation to cal to be a sign that mathfox is still early in development, and maybe not ready to be used in other projects.
SemVer, a common standard in packaging, requires packages >1.0.0 to only make "breaking changes" when going up a whole version, e.g. from 1.x.x to 2.0.0. Not everybody follows that, but if a project is still early in its lifecycle, it generally has more dramatic changes, and as it gets more users it has to be more careful about how it makes changes and warns users about upcoming changes. (That's not to say it isn't a good project or that you shouldn't use it--if you're interested, you could see if the author is interested in getting help improving it!)

Thank you - very helpful. Tried using math, but didn't know I needed "math." in front of the function. I thought I was simply having the same issue. Much appreciated.
